# Incrementing Count within a Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to get an incrementing counter within a set of results.

For example, assume I have a `messages` table:

```
messages
--------
- id (int)
- user_id (int)
- sent_at (date)
- body (text)
```

I'd like to perform a query that gives me results like this:

```
+---------+------------+-------------+---------+
| user_id | message_id | sent_at     | counter |
+---------+------------+-------------+---------+
|       1 |          1 |  2017-01-01 |       1 |
|       1 |          3 |  2017-01-15 |       2 |
|       1 |          4 |  2017-01-22 |       3 |
|       2 |          2 |  2017-01-06 |       1 |
|       2 |          6 |  2017-01-22 |       2 |
|       3 |          5 |  2017-01-22 |       1 |
|       3 |          7 |  2017-01-28 |       2 |
|       3 |          8 |  2017-02-03 |       3 |
|       3 |          9 |  2017-02-14 |       4 |
+---------+------------+-------------+---------+
```

Essentially, the counter increments exclusively within the `user_id` group, and each internal group is ordered by the `sent_at` column.

I know that I can easily get the first three columns with the following SQL:

```
SELECT
   user_id,
   id AS message_id,
   sent_at
FROM messages
ORDER BY
    user_id,
    sent_at
```

But I'm in need of that fourth `count` column.

I know that I can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the result row number:

```
SELECT
   user_id,
   id AS message_id,
   sent_at,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY user_id, sent_at) AS counter
FROM messages
ORDER BY
    user_id,
    sent_at
```

But that gives me the following results:

```
+---------+------------+-------------+---------+
| user_id | message_id | sent_at     | counter |
+---------+------------+-------------+---------+
|       1 |          1 |  2017-01-01 |       1 |
|       1 |          3 |  2017-01-15 |       2 |
|       1 |          4 |  2017-01-22 |       3 |
|       2 |          2 |  2017-01-06 |       4 |
|       2 |          6 |  2017-01-22 |       5 |
|       3 |          5 |  2017-01-22 |       6 |
|       3 |          7 |  2017-01-28 |       7 |
|       3 |          8 |  2017-02-03 |       8 |
|       3 |          9 |  2017-02-14 |       9 |
+---------+------------+-------------+---------+
```

If I could reset the counter somehow after each new `user_id`, I'd get the result that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to simply use `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT
   user_id,
   id AS message_id,
   sent_at,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY user_id, sent_at) AS counter
FROM messages
ORDER BY
    user_id,
    sent_at;
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `row_number` is the right way to go. You're just missing a `partition by` clause to get a new counter for each distinct `user_id`:

```
SELECT
   user_id,
   id AS message_id,
   sent_at,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY sent_at) AS counter
   -- Here ----------^
FROM messages
ORDER BY
    user_id,
    sent_at
```

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for `partition by`:

```
SELECT user_id, id AS message_id, sent_at,
       row_number() over (partition by user_id order by sent_at) AS counter
FROM messages m
ORDER BY user_id, sent_at;
```